# Transform non-orthogonal lattice vectors to orthogonal lattice vectors

Tags: orthogonality, crystallography

Let's say I have an FCC lattice with lattice vectors:

```
a = 1.0 -1.0 -1.0
b = 1.0  1.0 -1.0
c = 1.5  0.0  2.5
```

How do I convert these to orthogonalise them?

Comment: If you orthogonalize them they won't be lattice vectors anymore, right?

Comment: @runway44 exactly, that is why I wanted to know how can we get orthogonal lattice vectors for this cell. Since the lattice is FCC, there must be orthogonal lattice vectors.